# Prove that $\prod\limits_{k=1}^n(4-\tfrac{2}{k}) \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory, products

How to prove that 
$$\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\left(4-\dfrac{2}{k}\right) \in \mathbb{N}.\tag{1}$$

Moreover, that it is even number.

---

**Update:**
sos440 give me great hint on $(1)$.

And how about this one:
$$\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\left(4+\dfrac{2}{k}\right) \in \mathbb{N}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: You can observe that the product equals $\binom{2n}{n} = 2\binom{2n-1}{n}$.

Comment: @sos440, thank you. I didn't observed it earlier.

Comment: Isn't the second one just $(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}$?

Comment: @IvanLoh, thank you too. All the question is solved in comments :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example: $$\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\left(4+\dfrac{2}{k}\right) = 2^n \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots 2n+1  }{1 \cdot 2 \cdots n} = 2^n \frac{(2n)! (2n+1)}{n!  (n!)2^n}=(2n +1) {2n \choose n}$$

Answer (score 2):

The first one is already given in the comments. The relationship between first one and second one can be seen by

$$
k_n=\prod_{k=1}^n(4-\frac{2}{k})=\frac{2.6.10.14.18\dots (4n-2)}{1.2.3.4.5\dots n}
$$

$$
\prod_{k=1}^n(4+\frac{2}{k})=\frac{6.10.14.18\dots(4n-2)(4n+2)}{1.2.3.4.5\dots n}=k_n/2+4n+2
$$